# Are CPU temperatures over 110 something to worry about?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, cpu, temperature

I am primarily a Java developer and love using OS X and Mac as my primary development environment.

However recently I have been having temperature and heat concerns. I have a piece of code that parses at 4.5 GB XML file, and when this method is running the CPU temperature immediately goes over 90 degrees, and after a few minutes its over 110. At that point I stop the process because I’m worried about damaging my machine.

The fans are running at over 6000 RPM but the temperature continues to climb. Is this normal behavior? I’m worried I’m going to blow my CPU. I have a 2012 MBP Retina 15 inch, and it literally just went out of warranty/AppleCare.

I should mention that when I have IntelliJ IDEA (Java IDE), SQL Developer, Firefox open, and a Tomcat server running my CPU temps are around 60 to 70 degrees' sometimes in the low 80s.

Comment: It may seem stupid but have you already open the bottom of you MacBook Pro to clean the dust inside ?

Comment: I'm going to dupe this - see the other related questions. Even 90 C isn't a concern according to all the answers that have decent amount of up votes. Feel free to edit this to explain what temperature the CPU levels out at, what the other sensors are reading (especially ambient Air temperature). It sure seems fine, but be sure to explain if your degrees are F or C in the edit.